# Possible stack corruption during use of QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt

I'm dealing with what I suspect to be a stack corruption bug in a program that occurs during the use of `QNetworkAccessManager`. Full source code is available [here](https://github.com/pieterdd/AptNotifier).

Judging from log output, I'm guessing that the bug is triggered after the asynchronous request on line 44 in [calendar.cpp](https://github.com/pieterdd/AptNotifier/blob/master/src/model/calendar.cpp). I don't have solid evidence of this; I've only noticed that the message on line 45 is the last log message most of the time.

Here are lines 39-46:

```
void Calendar::update()
{
    // Start calendar download asynchronously. After retrieving the
    // file, parseNetworkResponse will take over.
    Logger::instance()->add(CLASSNAME, "Fetching update for 0x" + QString::number((unsigned)this, 16) + "...");
    _naMgr.get(QNetworkRequest(_url));
    Logger::instance()->add(CLASSNAME, "Update request for 0x" + QString::number((unsigned)this, 16) + " was filed.");
}
```

This HTTP GET request is handled by the `Calendar::parseNetworkResponse` slot, which is connected to `_naMgr`'s `finished` signal. Here are lines 170-174:

```
void Calendar::parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    // TODO: we suspect that sometimes a SIGSEGV occurs within the bounds
    // of this function. We'll remove the excessive log calls when we've
    // successfully tracked down the problem.
    Logger::instance()->add(CLASSNAME, "Got update response for 0x" + QString::number((unsigned)this, 16) + ".");
```

Even when the log message on line 45 isn't the last to appear in the log after a crash, there is always an update request in the log that is never followed up by the log message at line 174. This leads me to believe that an HTTP GET request might be ruining things here. The URLs for which GET requests are filed appear to be correct.

One of the reasons why I think there's memory corruption involved is that the bug doesn't consistently pop up even though the list of input calendars and the status of my internet connection remain the same. (I can trigger the bug with a minimum of 2 calendars.) Furthermore I saw [this GCC output](http://pastebin.com/Bt3FGywD) when I tried to learn more about the point of failure. I would have collected output from `valgrind`'s memory checker to collect additional info but I don't have a working Linux installation nearby at the moment.

Can this bug be related to incorrect use of Qt's network libraries from my side? Have you got any other theories as to what might be causing the issue? This is my first time dealing with possible stack corruption and since I'm doing this solo hobby project in my spare time I don't have anyone to train me in dealing with these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your finished slot, when you are processing the response set a global flag (bool) to "processing"

That way, if you get another response, you can either queue it up, or you can ignore it. The problem is probably more due to the fact that QNetworkAccessManager forks a thread to do its processing somewhere behind the scenes, which causes your code to perform access violations.

If you want I will jump on your project and have a closer look :)

~ Dan

My class for sending and receiving:

.h file

```
class sendRec : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    sendRec(QObject *parent = 0);
    sendRec(QUrl);
    QString lastError;
    QUrl thisURL;
    //QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    //FUNCTIONS
    void doGet();
    void doPost(QByteArray*);
    void doPut(QString, QString);
    void doConnects(QNetworkReply *reply, QNetworkAccessManager *manager);

signals:
    void sendResponse(bool, QString*);
public slots:

    /** NETWORK_ACCESS_MANAGER_SLOT **/
    //SUCCESS SLOTS FOR BOTH
    void requestReturned(QNetworkReply * reply );
    //FAILURE SLOTS
    void proxyAuthFail(const QNetworkProxy & proxy, QAuthenticator * authenticator);
    void sslErrorFail(QNetworkReply * reply, const QList<QSslError> & errors);
    /** QNETWORK_REPLY_SLOTS **/
    //FAILURE SLOTS
    void reqError ( QNetworkReply::NetworkError code );
    void sslError ( const QList<QSslError> & errors );

};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "sendrec.h"

sendRec::sendRec(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}


sendRec::sendRec(QUrl url) {
    thisURL = url;
}

void sendRec::doGet() {
    QNetworkRequest request(thisURL);
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    doConnects(reply, manager);
}

void sendRec::doPost(QByteArray *message) {
    QNetworkRequest request(thisURL);
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, *message);
    doConnects(reply, manager);
}

void sendRec::doConnects(QNetworkReply *reply, QNetworkAccessManager* manager){
    //Reply Connects
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
                     this, SLOT(reqError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
                     this, SLOT(sslError(QList<QSslError>)));
    //manager connects
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
               this, SLOT(requestReturned(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)),
            this, SLOT(sslErrorFail(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(proxyAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkProxy,QAuthenticator*)),
               this, SLOT(proxyAuthFail(QNetworkProxy,QAuthenticator*)));


}


void sendRec::requestReturned(QNetworkReply * rep ){
    qDebug() << "Request Returned";
    QVariant status = rep->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    if(status != 200 || status == NULL) {
        QString *lastError = new QString("ERROR: " + status.toString()
                                         + " " + rep->readAll());
        emit sendResponse(false, lastError);
    } else {
        QString *retString = new QString(rep->readAll());
        *retString = retString->trimmed();
        emit sendResponse(true, retString);
    }
    rep->manager()->deleteResource(rep->request());
    rep->manager()->deleteLater();
    rep->deleteLater();
    sender()->deleteLater();


}
```

Comment: I thought that `Calendar::parseNetworkResponse` always got executed on the receiver thread because my [`Qt::ConnectionType`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) is set to `Qt::AutoConnection`. Wouldn't this mean that `Calendar::parseNetworkResponse` is never being executed in multiple threads at the same time? Or perhaps I don't quite understand the inner mechanics of `QNetworkAccessManager` yet.

Comment: There is a lot of behind the scenes stuff with it. I have written a very complicated program that uses it. I learned a lot from this website here: http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/07/why-qnetworkaccessmanager-should-not-have-the-finishedqnetworkreply-signal/

Comment: like i said earlier, its always good to have a wrapper class for this kind of thing :)

Comment: If I understand the article correctly, I should define a signal/slot connection for the `QNetworkReply` instead of the `QNetworkAccessManager` and deduce the `QNetworkReply*` that `finished()` would normally take by calling `QObject::sender()`. But then again, a call to `sender()` violates OOP principles according to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#sender). I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I have added my class that sends and receives messages. This has been exposed to about 10,000 hours testing and seems to stand up quite well :)

Comment: I rewrote my code to `connect` to the `QNetworkReply*` instead of the `QNetworkAccessManager*` (like the article you posted suggested) and at the moment it appears to be working. Then again these memory bugs don't pop up all the time, so I'm gonna give it a few days before I jump to conclusions. If the problem persists, I will take your code and see how I can fit it into my program. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: No worries, hopefully it helps other people out if they have the same issues - Always happy to help people contributing to the OS community :)

Comment: Just wanted to come back here for a sec and give an update: using `QNetworkReply*` didn't fix the problem after all, but then I [adapted](https://github.com/pieterdd/AptNotifier/blob/master/src/model/httpdownloader.cpp) your code for my project. It has been smooth sailing so far!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending off two requests at once?

I had an issue with threading and QNetworkAccessManager, i had to write a wrapper for it.

Ok, I read some of your code, check out the QT doco for QNetworkAccessManager, aside from the finished signal, there are a couple of other signals that get emitted on failure - its always good practice to catch these.

Is there any chance that you are sending another get request before you finish processing the response, this would explain why it is intermittent.

I will keep looking though and see if I can help.

~ Dan

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to analyze my code. While I was digging around I also found a null pointer bug (*calendar.cpp:207*) that occurs when you add something that isn't a valid ICS file. *"Are you sending off two requests at once?"* Good that you mention that... I might have to use a mutex in `Calendar::update`. I'll investigate.

Comment: I made sure that no two GET requests can be initiated at the same time, but it's still possible that a new GET request gets filed while the first one hasn't received a response yet. Is there a way to cancel the old GET request (thereby closing the opened TCP connection) to accommodate the new request? I made some changes - one of which was catching other `QNetworkAccessManager`-related signals like you suggested - but I can still trigger the bug.